# Create a new referenceContainer for specific CMS page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend

How would you create a new `referenceContainer` in Magento 2 on home page only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new layout named **`cms_index_index`** into `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<package>/Magento_CMS/layout`

You will then be able to reference what you need inside it, by example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="CONTAINERNAME">
        // stuff
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your module layout default.xml

Here i have taken `header.container` as a reference and added a new container inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.containertwo" as="header_containertwo" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-mini-container" after="header.panel.wrapper"/>
    </referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

In the test.phtml

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;" id="test123"><p>This is a test</p></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this add this container to all pages? Only need it on home page.

Comment: If you want to add only specific page , Go to specific cms page (in your case it is home page) Design ->  Layout Update XML -> Add the Xml code.