# Magento 2.2 Theme Layout

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, page-layouts

Can anyone elaborate the theme structure of Magento 2.2. I already refer the Theme document for it.

Also I want to change the category page layout so please guide me.

Category description block is hide if I change the `referenceContainer` name(`column.top`) in `catalog_category_view.xml` file, so please elabore what is the `column.top` and where it is define in the magento.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have page layout declaration 
Magento_Theme_module_dir/view/frontend/layouts.xml or in your theme

And page layouts for example:
Magento_Theme_module_dir/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml or your theme

Page layout is used also in categories.

Reference:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html

Comment: I already refer this one but my question is "column.top" and what is the use of it. May i change this as some.xyz or etc?

Comment: Maybe this will help, It looks like he change name of refereneContainer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137428/create-a-new-referencecontainer-for-specific-cms-page-in-magento-2   and also you can <referenceContainer name="container.name" display="false" />